# ETA Canada question about charges and offenses

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, international-travel

I've been searching a lot on the internet. If I'm charged with an offence in my country and the offence is not something punishable for a maximum of 10 years in Canada do I need to get a new ETA? Because I applied last year and answered no to the question.

I have no criminal record and no convictions. Will this be a problem at the border?

Comment: VTC: Without mention of the charge, it's impossible to know whether a new eTA would be an option (or visa), or what would happen at the border. OP has not returned since posting.